# How to handle reboot,shut down during installation of GUI and CLI mode

Tags: install4j

-How to handle reboot and power off scenarios while installation like how to roll back the installation if reboot and shutdown happens through install4j.
-How to change name of resource folder

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 8, there is no functionality to perform rollbacks on power-loss or process crashes.

Comment: Is there is any way or workaround to handle such scenario in Linux?

Comment: No sorry, this is just not an available feature. It would be very difficult to provide a safe rollback from a terminated installer process.